# Running digital ground at AC line potential (not neutral)

Tags: safety, home-automation

I've run across an interesting WiFi dimmer module known as a [Shelly dimmer](https://shelly.cloud/wifi-smart-home-automation-shelly-dimmer/).   This bright green module is designed to be used *inside* an electrical box.  Most of it's user interface is over line-voltage screw terminals (or via WiFi.)

In addition they have a recessed reset button and 6-pin programming/debug header.  It is mostly documented as for being used when not connected to A/C mains.

Doing some more reading, I understand that the "GND" pin on this is generally running at A/C "line" potential.   The power supply is clearly not galvanically isolated, which seems OK given its intended operating environment.

My primary question is what advantage is there to choosing L rather than N to make the digital ground?

Second question, any guess as to what sort circuit they use to generate their 3.3V DC supply while connected to the mains?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My primary question is what advantage is there to choosing L rather than N to make the digital ground?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fODOyu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The circuit is referenced to L to allow direct triggering of the triac without need for opto-triac or gate pulse transformer.*

The wall box has live-in, switched live-out and neutral. Since the neutral return from the lamp may not be available that's not an option and switching the live is a little bit safer when changing the light bulb. (I say a little because a triac would not be considered a safety isolation device.)

> Second question, any guess as to what sort circuit they use to generate their 3.3 V DC supply while connected to the mains?

Probably a capacitive voltage dropper power supply. A web search should provide plenty of examples - many very dodgy ones.

Comment: So in effect, this looks like a capacitive dropper intentionally plugged in "the wrong way".  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, L is the common with most of the voltage being dropped across a capacitor connected to N.

Comment: re: 3.3VDC from 220VAC - the Shelly 1 uses a LNK304DN (https://www.power.com/sites/default/files/product-docs/lnk302_304-306.pdf) to convert mains to 12V ... and then I suppose they drop it down to 3.3VDC using a standard regulator.  I've not seen the internals of the Dimmer, but I suppose similar.